# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am getting a strange error.

Another answer says it has to do with improper imports. I have tried declaring a few ways, like `var render_product_url = function()....` and so on, all fail.

AddRendering.js

```
import React from "react"


export function add_rendering(headers, target_header, rendering_callback) {
    var new_headers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++){
        var this_header = headers[i];
        if (this_header == target_header){
            var header_object = {
                title: target_header,
                render: rendering_callback
            };
            new_headers.push(header_object);
        } else {
            new_headers.push(this_header);
        }
    }
    return new_headers
}

function render_product_url(val, row) {
    return (<a href={"http://www.website.com/product/" + row[target_header]} target="_blank">{row[target_header]}</a>)
}

export function render_product_url_in_datatable(headers, target_header) {
    return add_rendering(
        headers,
        target_header,
        render_product_url
    )
}
```

ThisController.js

```
import React from "react"
import { render_product_url_in_datatable } from '../commonutils/AddRendering';


render() {
  ..
  these_metrics.headers = render_product_url_in_datatable(these_metrics.headers, 'Part Number');
  ..
}
```

the weirdest part is this works:

```
import React from "react"


export function add_rendering(headers, target_header, rendering_callback) {
    var new_headers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++){
        var this_header = headers[i];
        if (this_header == target_header){
            var header_object = {
                title: target_header,
                render: rendering_callback
            };
            new_headers.push(header_object);
        } else {
            new_headers.push(this_header);
        }
    }
    return new_headers
}

// function render_product_url(val, row) {
//     return (<a href={"http://www.website.com/p/" + row[target_header]} target="_blank">{row[target_header]}</a>)
// }

export function render_product_url_in_datatable(headers, target_header) {
    return add_rendering(
        headers,
        target_header,
        function render_product_url(val, row) {
            return (<a href={"http://www.website.com/p/" + row[target_header]} target="_blank">{row[target_header]}</a>)
        }
    )
}
```

anonymous also works, like

```
return add_rendering(
            headers,
            target_header,
            function(val, row) {
              ..
            }
```

I'm finding this JS import syntax unwieldy compared to normal languages, but this is normal for JS.

Why can you not use a function declared elsewhere in a file in JavaScript? This is using ES6 and React.

Comment: Strange that you even get there, since `target_header` isn’t in scope.

Comment: I believe it's passing in what it gets from `render_product_url_in_datatable(headers, target_header)`

Comment: @codyc4321, when it's inside the `render_product_url_in_datatable` it can get it from the function parameter, but in your first example the other function (`render_product_url`) doesn't have `target_header` on scope.

Comment: ohhh that makes sense. after an earlier export/import error I was biased to assume my export syntax was wrong. Thanks

Comment: If you write answer I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `AddRendering.js` either you did not post the entire code (missing some imports or something?) or you forgot to include `target_header` as a parameter in the `render_product_url` function (what is that `val` param though?).

```
function render_product_url(val, row) {
    return (<a href={"http://www.website.com/product/" + row[target_header]} target="_blank">{row[target_header]}</a>)
}
```

If this is an import missing and you are not sure on how to `import` this is the way to go:

```
import target_header from './path/to/target_header'; // in case of a default export
import {target_header} from './path/to/target_header'; // in case of name export
```